# Почему htmlentities не может на 100% обезопасить от XSS?

Tags: javascript, html, безопасность, xss, xss-атака

На Stack Overflow и на других форумах в темах по защите от XSS видел, что люди говорят про то, что `htmlentities` не спасет во всех случаях, но почему, никто не говорит (или объяснено очень скупо).
Я не понимаю, почему в некоторых случаях `hmtlenties` может не помочь. Ведь эту функция заменяет все символы на html-сущности и поэтому любая вставка вредоносного кода превратиться в обычный текст.
Допустим на сайте пользователь оставил такой комментарий:
`<script>hack();alert("Вы взломаны")</script>`
Благодаря htmlentites в этом и подобных случаях XSS-атаки не произойдет.
Тогда в каких же случаях `htmlentites` может не помочь?
Многие советуют для более полной защиты использовать HTML Purifier, но я абсолютно не понимаю почему нельзя обойтись лишь одним `htmlentitites()`

Comment: Если не использовать бездумно, то вполне обезопасит, а HTML Purifier вообще для другого

Comment: А пример *бездумного* использования можно посмотреть прямо в документации php, в первом комментарии https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlentities.php#99896